# How do I make a jsonschema so that it validates all objects in array?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate a JSON input using json-schema but it does not work like I need it to.

I have the following input JSON (part of it):

```
[
  {
    "admin_state": "disabled"
  },
  {
    "state": "disabled"
  }
]
```

And the following json-schema (part of it as well):

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "admin_state": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "enabled",
          "enum": [
            "disabled",
            "enabled"
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ],
  "minItems": 1
}
```

I want the validation to fail because of the "state" property that should not be allowed (thanks to the **"additionalProperties": false** option)

However, I can add/change anything in the second item in the array, validation is always successful. When I change anything in the first item, validation fails (as expected).

What did I miss?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSON Schema draft 7 states...

> If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the
> array successfully validate against that schema.
>
> If "items" is an array of schemas, validation succeeds if each element
> of the instance validates against the schema at the same position, if
> any.

In your schema, `items` is an array, which means you were only applying the subschem in that array to the first element of your instance's array. Simply remove the square braces from `items`, and your subschema will be applicabale to ALL items in the instance.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "admin_state": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "enabled",
        "enum": [
          "disabled",
          "enabled"
        ]
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
  "minItems": 1
}
```

Comment: Makes total sense now, thanks for your clear explanation.I just tested it and it works perfectly!

Comment: Feel free to upvote answers as well as accept them =] Also feel free to join the JSON Schema slack should you have any questions which you cannot ask here (or just join anyway).

Comment: @Relequestual you saved me a lot of time. Online schema generatoros had added square brackets everywhere.

Comment: This just saved me some future catastrophic data cleanup! Thank you!